# Display the header that a TODO item belongs to?

Tags: org-mode, formatting

In org mode, I'll have a file pertaining to some topic, and a few top level headings pertaining to instances of that topic, which may contain TODOs (also potentially nested). In the global TODO list, TODOs show up like this:

```
<file-name>:     <state> <name>
```

Would it be possible to instead display them like this (potentially with a custom format string):

```
<header> (<file-name>):      <state> <name>
```

Thanks!

Comment: See also `:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Foo
:END:
` under any given heading to have that show up in the Agenda...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize the `todo` part of `org-agenda-prefix-format` and add the breadcrumbs placeholder `%b`. For example, by default `org-agenda-prefix-format` has the value

```el
((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
 (todo . " %i %-12:c")
 (tags . " %i %-12:c")
 (search . " %i %-12:c"))
```

and a `TODO` entry for a second-level `Home` headline under a top-level `Tasks` headline, looks like this:

> Home:       TODO Work on music DB

If you change the `todo` entry in `org-agenda-prefix-format` from `" %i %-12:c"` to `" %b %i %-12:c"`, the same entry is shown as

> Tasks->  Home:       TODO Work on music DB

Breadcrumbs include *all* the higher level headlines.

In order to do the above change, first do `C-h v org-agenda-prefix-format`, and click on the `customize` link. In the resulting display, the values can be edited directly: find the `todo` entry and its format and change it as above. Then click `Apply` to try it out or `Apply and Save` to save it for future sessions as well.